# Android facebook sdk, requesting publish permission “publish_actions” isn't updating session permissions list

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to request for the permission "publish_actions" after the facebook account is linked. But whenever I make the request it does NOT add to the list of permissions in Session.getPermissions().

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

buttonPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null) {

        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);   
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
       }

       // publish story code
       publishStory();
     }
});

// Facebook Session Call Back   
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {

        if (session.isOpened()) {

            if (pendingPublishReauthorization && state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
                publishStory();
            }
        }
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

public static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
```

appears in logCat

```
01-07 14:51:39.882: D/FacbookPostAdmin(6685): Session State: OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED
01-07 14:51:39.882: D/FacbookPostAdmin(6685): Session Permissions: [public_profile]
```

also in Graph API Explorer

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing the permissions dialog pop up and ask you to accept the new permission?

Comment: Ming Li : No Permissions Dialog is not Showing. Its going to the Facebook app but don't know why dialog is not open and its coming back with OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED

Comment: Do you have publish_actions approved for your app? Or are you calling with a user with admin/developer/tester roles in your app?

Comment: when i am using user with tester role then permission dialog is popup but when with normal user dialog is not showing. may be i have to approved publish_action for my app.

Comment: any updates since then? i have same issue

Comment: @Mansi that's correct. If you want people outside of the Admin/Developer/Tester roles to use that feature, you need to have both your app in Public mode, and have publish_actions approved.

Comment: How can I get my publish actions approved ?